# Atributo json undefined

Tags: react-native

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou com o problema que não consigo acessar o atributo APLICACOES do `json`, ele retorna sempre `undefined`.

Ao executar `console.log(aplic[0])` ele imprime esse `json`, porém se dou um `console.log(aplic[0].APLICACOES)` ele não mostra os 4 objetos filho de aplicações.

Alguém sabe o porque disso estar acontecendo? ou o que devo fazer para resolver esse problema.

Obrigado

[image: json]

```
function getAplicacoesAtividadesAgricolasBD(idAtividadeAgricola) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const aplicacoes = [];
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ATIVIDADE_AGRICOLA_APLICACAO WHERE ID_ATIVIDADE_AGRICOLA = ?',
            [idAtividadeAgricola], (tx, results) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    const aplic = results.rows.item(i);
                    aplicacoes.push(aplic);
                }

                resolve(aplicacoes);
            }, () => {
                reject('Erro ao consultar dados. Por favor, tente novamente!');
            });
    });
});


function getDataDBAtividadeAgricolaById(idPropriedade, idAtividadeAgricola) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const aplicacoes = [];
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ATIVIDADE_AGRICOLA WHERE (ID_PROPRIEDADE = ?) AND (ID_ATIVIDADE_AGRICOLA = ?)',
            [idPropriedade, idAtividadeAgricola], (tx, results) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    const aplic = results.rows.item(i);

                    getAplicacoesAtividadesAgricolasBD(aplic.ID_ATIVIDADE_AGRICOLA)
                        .then(itens => {
                            aplic['APLICACOES'] = itens;
                        });
                    aplicacoes.push(aplic);
                }

                resolve(aplicacoes);
            }, (err) => {
                reject('Erro ao consultar dados. Por favor, tente novamente!');
            });
    });
});

export function visualizarAtividadeAgricolaModal(idPropriedade, idAtividadeAgricola) {
return async (dispatch) => {
    getDataDBAtividadeAgricolaById(idPropriedade, idAtividadeAgricola)
        .then(aplic => {
            console.log(aplic[0]);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(aplic[0]));
            console.log(aplic[0].APLICACOES);
            dispatch({
                type: AGR_AA_SET_ATIVIDADE_AGRICOLA_VIEW,
                data: aplic[0]
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            Alert.alert('Atenção!', 'Erro ao consultar dados. Por favor, tente novamente!');
        });
};
```

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(aplic)). Manda o resultado disso pra gente ver

Comment: Blza. já posto o código e n imagem. Quanto a saida de console.log(JSON.stringify(aplic)), realmente aqui não consta o atributo APLICACOES..  Deixa eu postar o codigo que estou usando que fica melhor para vcs me ajudarem. Será que pode ser alguma sincronização do redux?

Comment: Ja tentou passar `x = aplic[0].APLICACOES` a uma variavel e dessa variavel tomar `x[0]` ?

Answer (score 0):

O

```
aplic[0].APLICACOES
```

contem um array. Portanto seria necessário usar uma função map para exibir os elementos. Seria algo assim:

```
Object.keys(aplic[0].APLICACOES).map((key) => console.log(aplic[0].APLICACOES[key]))
```